# Is django-cors-headers necessary when operating on a subdomain?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, cross-domain, subdomain, single-page-application

I plan to run Django as an API with django-rest-framework. This API will power a Vue.js web app hosted on a separate platform.

If the API is configured to run on api.example.com and the web app to run on www.example.com, is django-cors-headers required for the API to process requests from the frontend?

Also, how does this work with cookies? Is authenticate via http-only cookies, with no localstorage of tokens possible with this setup?

Comment: I cannot give a canonical answer, but cors looks required. Also, you need to handle csrf, and just disabling it is not secure approach, a better way is to disable session auth and use jwt or similar auth via headers.

Comment: Do you think it's better to pass on the HttpOnly cookie authentication then? I hoped to avoid storing tokens, but cookies might not be feasible with this setup